# Anchor elements to it's siblings

Tags: html, css, layout

Would it be possible to hava a anchored layout something like the following with HTML & CSS only?

```
+- #parent ------
| +-# elem1 ---
| | Varibale height (depends on content) - top anchored
| | to #parent (top: 0)
| |
| +------------
| +-# elem2 ---
| | Varibale height (depends on content) - top anchored
| | to #elem1 bottom and bottom #anchored to #elem3 top
| |
| +------------
| +-# elem3 ---
| | Fixed height - top anchored to #elem2 bottom and
| | bottom anchored to #parent bottom (bottom: 0)
| |
| +------------
+----------------
```

Edit: The #parent element height may be fixed and I'm looking for something similar to this:

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtquick-components-symbian-1.1/examples-native-scalability-anchors.html

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qt-maemo/anchor-layout.html

Comment: no.. you will need javascript or jquery to do this, but ya if you want to show it expanded view than yes you can

Comment: Isn't that the default behavior?

Comment: It's logically not possible to have both elem2 bottom anchored to #elem3 top *AND* #elem3 top anchored to #elem2 bottom. They can't both be anchored to each other. But is that what you really meant?

Comment: @Juhana--That depends. "Yes" if parent height is not fixed, as it will expand with the children. "No" if it is fixed (hence Faust's question) and `#elem1` is determining the space left for `#elem2` to take up.

Comment: @Juhana I guess he is asking for hierarchy menu kind of thing

Comment: I'm not really seeing how elem2 could be "variable height depending on content" and at the same time be anchored both from top and bottom.

Comment: Faust, ScottS - Yes the #parent height may be fixed
Mr. Alien - No - I'm asking for a layout kind of thing - something similar to this one: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtquick-components-symbian-1.1/examples-native-scalability-anchors.html ... suppose that's not possible with html + css only

Answer (score 0):

Have I misunderstood, or is this what you want - http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/rkKqy/ - ?

The HTML

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">varaible height child</div>
    <div class="child">varaible height child</div>
    <div class="child">fixed height child</div>
</div>​
```

The CSS

```
.parent {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 50px; //equal to last-child's height
}

.child:first-child {
    /*styles for the first-child here*/
}

.child:nth-child(2) {
    /*styles for the second-child here*/
}

.child:last-child {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px; //the fixed height
    /*anymore styles for the last-child here*/
}
​
```